# What type of study?

Tags: terminology, reliability, case-control-study

I calculated inter-rater reliability for a medical test. We applied the test on both healthy people and people with a specific disease and then two raters interpreted the test. Can I call this study a case-control even though I didn't look for exposure / risk factors?

Answer (score 1):

That is what

```
@ARTICLE{lijmer99,
  author = {Lijmer, J G and Mol, B W and Heisterkamp, S and Bonsel, G J and
           Prins, M H and van der Meulen, J H P and Bossuyt, P M M},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Empirical evidence of design-related bias in studies of diagnostic
          tests},
  journal = {Journal of the American Medical Association},
  volume = 282,
  pages = {1061--1066}
}
```

callas them so yes.